# {configurable:false} or Object.seal() is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, immutability, defineproperty

I am trying to learn javascript, and have seen that we can play with object's property's attributes. (i mean **value**, **writable**, **enumerable**, **configurable**).

And from what i learned, i have thought changing **{configurable: false}** would restrict any more configuration changes like **{writable: false, enumerable: false}**

I have written below to try it out, but the results i have got were nothing like the results i have expected.

Am i wrong about what **{configurable:false}** means or, is there something wrong with the code? TIA.

```js
"use strict";

window.onload = function(){

  var o = {x:1};

  //Make "x" non-configurable
  Object.defineProperty(o, "x", {configurable: false});
  //Seal "o";
  Object.seal(o);

  console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o, "x"));
  //outputs => Object { value: 1, writable: true, enumerable: true, configurable: false }
  console.log(Object.isSealed(o));
  //outputs => true

  Object.defineProperty(o, "x", {writable: false}); //this doesn't cause any errors.
  console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o, "x"));
  //outputs => Object { value: 1, writable: false, enumerable: true, configurable: false }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MDN** - [seal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal)

> **Configurable attribute**
>   The configurable attribute controls at the same time whether the property can be deleted from the object and whether its attributes (other than writable to false) can be changed
>
> **The Object.seal()**
>  method seals an object, preventing new properties from being added to it and marking all existing properties as non-configurable. Values of present properties can still be changed as long as they are writable.

You need `freeze`

**MDN** - [freeze](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze)

> Comparison to Object.seal()
>   Objects sealed with Object.seal() can have their existing properties changed. Existing properties in objects frozen with Object.freeze() are made immutable.

```js
"use strict";

window.onload = function(){

  var o = {x:1};

  //Make "x" non-configurable
  Object.defineProperty(o, "x", {configurable: false});
  //freeze "o";
  Object.freeze(o);

  console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o, "x"));
  //outputs => Object { value: 1, writable: true, enumerable: true, configurable: false }
  console.log(Object.isSealed(o));
  //outputs => true

  Object.defineProperty(o, "x", {writable: true}); //Now this doesn't cause.
  console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o, "x"));
  //outputs => Object { value: 1, writable: false, enumerable: true, configurable: false }
}
```

Comment: thanks for introducing a new function, but i don't want all the properties to become read-only. Besides, setting writable to false was for an example purpose only. Why am i able to configure a property after sealing it and marking configrauble false

Comment: Because `seal` allows you to edit existing properties.

Comment: Your answer says otherwise The Object.seal() method seals an object, preventing new properties from being added to it and marking all existing properties as non-configurable. Am i not seeing how configurable:false works?

Comment: But still writable - `writable` is existing and can be changed, we cannot add new properties to it. Freezing it does block all mutation.

Comment: then, may i ask, what good is **configurable:false** for

Comment: See added explanation, it describes `configurable`

Comment: The first output should be `{value: 1, writable: false, enumerable: true, configurable: false}`

Comment: @grantonzhuang not when you `freeze` the object.